# Get all SPUser groups?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, spuser

I have a SPUser and I want to get all the user groups in which the SPUser exists. How can i get all the SPGroups containing the SPUser programatically?. Sample codes and useful links would be very helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do something like this..(I have not tested..pls debug and test)

```
List<string> lstgroup=new List<string>();

 SPGroupCollection groupCollection = web.Groups;
        foreach (SPGroup grp in groupCollection)
        {
            if (grp.ContainsCurrentUser)
            {
                lstgroup.add(grp);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

`SPUser.Groups` returns a collection of SPGroups which the user is a member. Here is the documentation  [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spuser.groups%28v=office.14%29.aspx)